# how to group by mode in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

i am trying to find the item belongs to which category based on mode by using below pandas data frame

data

```
   ITEM          CATEGORY
1  red saree     actual
2  red saree     actual
3  glass         lbh
4  glass         lbh
5  red saree     actual
6  red saree     lbh
7  glass         actual
8  bottle        actual
9  bottle        actual
```

what i am trying to figure out is by taking the unique items i want to assign a category to each unique item based on mode of category.

Expected output:

```
  ITEM          CATEGORY
1 red saree     actual
2 glass         lbh
3 bottle        actual
```

please tell me how to find out in python,Thanks in advance

tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mode
data_x = map(mode, data['category'])
```

I know it is not even related to that, but unable to find how to write the code for that

Comment: Where did `7 glass actual` go?

Comment: what i am asking is! , we have an item(glass) with 3 categories(actual,lbh,lbh), then the mode of the categories for item(glass) is lbh.   how can i assign using python

Comment: Why is it `lbh` and not `actual`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can groupy the 'ITEM' and 'CATEGORY' columns and then call `apply` on the df groupby object and pass the function [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html#pandas.DataFrame.mode). We can then call `reset_index` and pass param `drop=True` so that the multi-index is not added back as a column as you already have those columns:

```
In [161]:

df.groupby(['ITEM', 'CATEGORY']).apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[161]:
        ITEM CATEGORY
0     bottle   actual
1      glass      lbh
2  red saree   actual
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but i am supposed to say for example    :if we have values instead of types in categories varible. i need to find out the max value from that.   for eg: we have an item(glass) with 3 values(1.5,2.5,3.5), then the max of the categories for item(glass) is 3.5. And then i need to say that 3.5 belongs to 'actual' or 'LBH' .                  how can i find that using python

Comment: @surendra that's a new question please post as a brand new question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Pandas, you could always try `pandasql` and work with that if you're more comfortable with SQL.

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q = """
select 
    item, 
    category, 
    count(*) as cnt
from df
group by item, category
"""

df_counts = pysqldf(q)

q1 = """
select b.item, b.category 
from 
    (select 
        item, 
        max(cnt) as max_cnt
    from df_counts
    group by item) as a
    inner join df_counts as b
        on a.item = b.item 
            and a.max_cnt = b.cnt
"""
```

with the output:

```
>>> pysqldf(q1)
        item category
0  bottle      actual
1  glass          lbh
2  red saree   actual
```