# How to keep a specific duplicate from among duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates

I have a .csv file.

```
time,open,high,low,close,Extremum,Fib 1,Fib 2,Fib 3,l100,LS3,SS3,Volume,Volume MA
```

lots of rows like:

```
2022-04-08T02:00:00+02:00,43.431,43.44,43.431,43.44,44.669,43.58332033414956,43.28818411430672,43.11250779297169,42.91223678664976,,,78.07,
```

And there are duplicates, like 4 of them, with differences at "Extremum" column
Like this:

```
2022-04-07 17:10:25,41.622,41.625,41.622,41.625,43.6,42.38191401399852,42.05078384304666,41.85368255081341,41.6289870776675,41.007714285714286,,6.99,571.0029999999954
2022-04-07 17:10:25,41.622,41.625,41.622,41.625,41.589,42.64812186602502,42.93603848979882,43.10741743252131,43.30278942722496,,,6.99,571.0029999999954
2022-04-07 17:10:25,41.622,41.625,41.622,41.625,43.6,42.38191401399852,42.05078384304666,41.85368255081341,41.6289870776675,41.007714285714286,,6.99,571.0029999999954
2022-04-07 17:10:25,41.622,41.625,41.622,41.625,43.6,42.38191401399852,42.05078384304666,41.85368255081341,41.6289870776675,41.007714285714286,,6.99,571.0029999999954
```

Its sorted by 'time', axis=0 (its Column A, column 0 in calc sheet)

```
csvData.sort_values(by=["time"],axis=0,ascending=True,inplace=True,na_position='first')
```

Its 4 dupes at time 17:10:25, how to throw out the not matching one?

Here we have: 41.589, 43.6, 43.6, 43.6.
The 41.589 is wrong, and need to be out, and need to keep only 1 copy of remaining 3 dupes (that drop.duplicated can do, but it can't give me 4 dupes to process, it can be set only in 3 ways: keep='first', keep='last' or keep=False, and I need not existent keep=True.. I need return of all 4 dupes, to check which one is that 1 of 4 that's bad to out, before I unique_seen them all, to reduce only to 1, with correct 43.6 in this case. Does someone got any ideas how to achieve that?
Saw some ideas here at stack, but can't understand them enough to apply to my case, so I'm kindly asking for help.

Comment: you need to keep the 'mode'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216921/how-to-group-by-mode-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use twice `duplicated` with two different modes: `keep=False` and another of your choice. Then compute a boolean mask from those two for slicing.

Assuming this example dataset:

```
  date col  other
0    a   a      0
1    a   a      1
2    a   X      2   # unique
3    a   a      3
4    b   Y      4   # unique
5    b   b      5
6    b   b      6
7    b   b      7
```

You can use:

```
m1 = df.duplicated(subset=['date','col'])
m2 = df.duplicated(subset=['date','col'], keep=False)

df2 = df[m1!=m2]
```

Output:

```
  date col  other
0    a   a      0
5    b   b      5
```

Intermediates:

```
  date col  other     m1     m2  m1!=m2
0    a   a      0  False   True    True
1    a   a      1   True   True   False
2    a   X      2  False  False   False
3    a   a      3   True   True   False
4    b   Y      4  False  False   False
5    b   b      5  False   True    True
6    b   b      6   True   True   False
7    b   b      7   True   True   False
```

Comment: YES! That was it!  im so happy You answered! Altho got warning about "A value is trying to be a set on a copy of a slice from DataFrame" duno if it need more attention, because it works!

Comment: @ruskiem this warning come from a previous step in your code, you created a view of your dataframe during slicing. This can be an issue, or not... There are Q/A on this topic on the site.

Comment: Oh, can't see about what the warning is talking about, its realy only this code: https://pastebin.com/6acxC4jb